# Changing the size of the mouse pointer in Ubuntu MATE 18.04 does not work

Tags: 18.04, mouse, mate

I have Ubuntu 18.04 with the gnome-desktop  and parallel the Ubuntu MATE desktop installed.
While I can easily change the size of the mouse pointer (DMZ-White) in the Gnome3 desktop , this does not work on the MATE desktop.
I use for this the dconf-editor.

Maybe someone knows a solution?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should open MATE Control Center, navigate to *Appearance* (or run `mate-appearance-properties`) then select active theme and click *Customize* button, go to *Pointer* tab and then adjust *Size* slider:

[image: Customize Pointer]

The `dconf` command is the following:

```
dconf write /org/mate/desktop/peripherals/mouse/cursor-size 96
```

You can reset the value with:

```
dconf reset /org/mate/desktop/peripherals/mouse/cursor-size
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
for the dconf commands and the hint with the mate-control-center.

so far I have seen the maximal value vor my cursor ist 48
Thats the value when the slider of mouse size is at the right maximum.

In the dconf-editor I can select higher valuesbut the mouse will not be larger.
And then when I launch mate-appearance-properties the value will be set to 48.


In the dconf-editor is a maximal value for the mouse pointer of 2.147.483.647 shown
What the sense of this value? Is it only theoretically?

Comment: I have tested this approach on VirtualBox VM, it has 96 px max and this value persists after reboot. I'm not sure what is your issue.